# Only one instance of Polymer custom element rendered in core pages

Tags: polymer

I am learning how to use Polymer. I use the sample application provided with Polymer and try to extend it progressively. I am facing an issue with the core-pages element. I created 3 pages. Each of my pages contains the same custom element. I experience a strange behavior. Only the last instance of my custom element is rendered. In my example, only the one one the 3rd page is rendered. If I remove it, only the one of the 2nd page is rendered.

Any idea of what happen and how to fix this issue?

Here is the source code of my pages:

```
<core-scaffold id="myapp" mode="waterfall">
    <div tool flex >My first app</div>
    <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar>Options</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" selected="all" on-core-select="{{selectAction}}">
            <core-item name="all" icon="settings" label="All"></core-item>
            <core-item name="favorites" icon="account-box" label="Favorites"></core-item>
            <core-item name="page2" icon="account-box" label="2nd page"></core-item>
            <core-item name="page3" icon="account-box" label="3rd page fav"></core-item>
        </core-menu>            
    </core-header-panel>
    <div class="container" flex layout vertical center>         
        <core-pages  flex class="pages" selected="{{page}}" transitions="slide-from-right" fit>
            <div flex layout vertical center>
                <div><h1>Page 1</h1>    
                </br>
                <post-list id="AllPosts" show="all"></post-list>
                <h1>End Page 1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>              
            <div flex layout vertical center>
                <div>Page 2</div>
                </br>
                <div>
                <post-list id="AllPosts2" show="all"></post-list>
                </div>
                <div>End Page 2</div>
            </div>
            <div flex layout vertical center>
                <div>Page 3</div>
                <div>
                <post-list id="AllPosts3" show="all"></post-list>
                </div>
                <div>End Page 3</div>
            </div>              
        </core-pages>

    </div>
</core-scaffold>
```

Here is my custom element source code:

```
    <app-db id="db"></app-db>  
<div layout vertical center>
  <template repeat="{{oneuser in $.db.posts}}">
    <post-card favorite="false" hidden="false" username="toto"></post-card>
    <post-card favorite="{{oneuser.doc.favorite}}" on-favorite-tap="{{handleFavorite}}"
      hidden?="{{show == 'favorites' && !oneuser.doc.favorite}}"
      userimage="{{oneuser.doc.avatar}}" username="{{oneuser.doc.username}}" usermsg="{{oneuser.doc.text}}">      
    </post-card>        
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems your should use `core-animated-pages` instead of `core-pages` if you want to have a transition. Don't forgot to import the transition too `bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html`. Tell me if it helped on render. If it don't work, I think the problem is from your polymer layout. More information here https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

Comment: Thanks Thibaut for your help. In fact, I was initially using core-animated-pages, and I had the same behaviour. I will have a look to the polymer layout.

Comment: Did it. No improvement. If I look to the elements, I can only see a #document-fragment after the repeat template on my first page. On the last one, I can see multiple cards custom elements based on my database content.  It behaves as if my db data was used on my last page but not available anymore for the 2 previous pages. Maybe something with data binding?